# Link QT 32Bit libraries with 64 Bit Application (MinGW64 compiler )?

Tags: c++, qt, linker, qt4, 64-bit

Greetings all,

In my application I need to allocate memory beyong 4GB memory-address-space.So I need compile my application in 64Bit.

My development environment is QT 32 bit libraries(LGPL),and going to use MinGW64 to compile 64bit build.
Since QT doesnt support MinGW64 (only 32bit supported) , can I link 32Bit QT libraries against with my 64Bit application ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@umanga
My reply does not answer your question, but it might give you detail on what you actually want to do--building Qt 64-bit libraries using MinGW-w64.

As suggested by MSalters, porting Qt to the 64-bit environment may be simpler.  Also, Qt 4.7 is 99.99% compatible with current MinGW-w64.  I just tried building Qt 4.7 using MinGW-w64 myself this morning (Webkit is included, but Phonon is not).

You only need to modify one line of Qt source code to get a successful Qt build.  The detailed steps are provided in [my blog](http://pinyotae.blogspot.com/2010/11/building-64-bit-qt-47-using-mingw-w64.html) -- "after all, it *is* Open Source.".

Comment: hi , pinyote .thanks for the answer.Infact I asked about this in your blog :)

Answer (score 4):

No, you can't. 64-bit process cannot load 32-bit DLL.

Comment: +1. If you think about it, this makes sense -- what would the 32 bit code do if/when you handed it 64 bit pointers ;)

Comment: I only use 64bit pointers in my application data-structures.I am not going to interfere with 32 QT library.So I though ,while my application using 64bit address space , 32bit QT libs can use only 32bit address-space.

Comment: @umanga: still it can't be done, if you want to know why, each process has certain CPU defined structures that among other things, determine what mode the CPU is in (64-bit/32-bit) while executing that processes. A dll is just code/data loading into a process's address space at runtime, an application only has one address space and it can only be in one mode.

Comment: Well, technically, Microsoft did something similar in the switch from Win16 to Win32 (thunking). To put it mildly, that was **ugly**, but it can be done. However, thunking requires manual work, and it's probably far, far easier to port Qt to the 64 bits environment - after all, it _is_ Open Source.

Comment: @MSalters: yes, thunking is a viable option, but as you mentioned it is ugly and IMO generally a bad idea. One thing to note is that Qt doesn't need to be ported to 64-bit, it already works just fine. umanga may have to compile it himself though. I don't know if they offer 64-bit binaries for windows yet.